# Installing Yum in Fedora 12

Tags: installation, yum

For some reason I do not know, several default packages in my Fedora 12 installation have gone missing, removed or uninstalled. Now, reinstalling fedora 12 is not a good idea in my current situation. Can someone guide on how can I install yum package using rpm? I mean, I can't find the repository for yum.

Thank you very much!

UPDATE:

An Hour Later, I have installed yum successfully but installing all the missing dependencies one by one! Thanks everyone!

Comment: While you run from the console yum install rpm name what error do you get.

Comment: i don't have yum installed. so i'l definitely get an error... I've managed to get a yum tar.gz file from its official website, but I run into another package dependency when I tried to run it. libpython2.4.so.1.0. So I guess, is there any way to install yum and its dependencies with just rpm, or sources? how can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: so doing a `which yum` doesn't return anything?

Comment: now it returns something, after I tried to install yum from source a I got from its official page. But I run into dependencies issues i.e. python lib, when I tried running it.

Comment: what is your "python" version & which is "yum" version ?

Comment: am currently installing 2.4.* version of python... ;0

Comment: can use yum 3.0.1 - for you server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be in for a ride, especially if you're missing dependencies.
[Here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15048337/dir/fedora_12/com/yum-3.2.25-1.fc12.noarch.rpm.html) is a page where you can view mirrors of the RPM and its dependencies, and search for the dependencies you don't have, in case the following doesn't work.

```
rpm -Uvh ftp://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/pub/redhat.com/fedora/linux/releases/12/Everything/i386/os/Packages/yum-3.2.25-1.fc12.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: aah, getting to the dependencies individually is a bad idea...

Comment: Alternatively, ctrl+f the dep list against the [baserepo (X64)](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/)/[baserepo (i386)](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/) and install what's needed

Comment: that centralized list of x64 os packages would have helped me a lot..

Answer (score 1):

As @qweet pointed this is not a trivial thing due to the large number of prerequisites for yum, most notably python packages. My strategy would be

```
1. get the yum rpm (do not use source code) from a F12 repository (releases/12/Everything/i386/os/Packages/) and place in a fresh folder
2. try to install yum: rpm -Uvh ./yum.xxx.xxx.rpm
3. If dependencies have been deleted also then you will get plenty of complains
4. Download also one by one the dependencies
5. try #2 above again
6. repeat 4,5 until you have no errors!!
```

Of course if you have a F12 disk things get even easier.
Have fun